# How are binary classifiers generalised to classify data into arbitrarily large sets?

Tags: machine-learning

How can algorithms which partition a space in to halves, such as Suport Vector Machines, be generalised to label data with labels from sets such as the integers?

For example, a support vector machine operates by constructing a hyperplane and then things 'above' the hyperplane take one label, and things below it take the other label.

How does this get generalised so that the labels are, for example, integers, or some other arbitrarily large set?

Answer (score 5):

One option is the 'one-vs-all' approach, in which you create one classifier for each set you want to partition into, and select the set with the highest probability.

For example, say you want to classify objects with a label from `{1,2,3}`. Then you can create three binary classifiers:

- C1 = 1 or (not 1)
- C2 = 2 or (not 2)
- C3 = 3 or (not 3)

If you run these classifiers on a new piece of data X, then they might return:

- C1(X) = 31.6% chance of being in 1
- C2(X) = 63.3% chance of being in 2
- C3(X) = 89.3% chance of being in 3

Based on these outputs, you could classify X as most likely being from class 3. (The probabilities don't add up to 1 - that's because the classifiers don't know about each other).

If your output labels are ordered (with some kind of meaningful, rather than arbitrary ordering). For example, in finance you want to classify stocks into {BUY, SELL, HOLD}. Although you can't *legitimately* perform a regression on these (the data is [ordinal rather than ratio data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement)) you *can* assign the values of -1, 0 and 1 to SELL, HOLD and BUY and then *pretend* that you have ratio data. Sometimes this can give good results even though it's not theoretically justified.

Comment: How well does this work when my label set is perhaps integers between -1000 and 1000 though, or some other large label set? It becomes quite slow to create 2001 different classifiers.

Comment: @MrBones Check out Weka (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). It allows you to easily use LibSVM or LibLINEAR (adaptation of SVM which is sometimes more suited for large datasets) on datasets with many classes.

Comment: if the output is between -1000 and 1000 it is probably a continously varying or an ordinal variable rather than a categorical variable (the relative values have no meaning for the latter). In that case regression algorithms should be used instead of multi-class classification algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is the Cramer-Singer method ("On the algorithmic implementation of multiclass kernel-based vector machines").
Svmlight implements it here: http://svmlight.joachims.org/svm_multiclass.html.

Classification into an infinite set (such as the set of integers) is called ordinal regression. Usually this is done by mapping a range of continuous values onto an element of the set. (see http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/chu05a.pdf, Figure 1a)